# Are boost::unique_locks granted in the order that they are called?

Tags: boost, locking, queue, boost-mutex, contention

I've examined the documentation on [Boost Synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), and I cannot seem to determine if a `boost::unique_lock` will attain its lock in order.

In other words, if two threads are contending to lock a mutex which is already locked, will the order that they attempt to lock be maintained after the lock is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique lock is not a lock (it's a lock adaptor that can act on any Lockable or TimedLockable type, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)).

The order in which threads get the lock (or resources in general) is likely implementation defined. These implementations usually have well-documented scheduling semantics, so applications can avoid resource starvation, soft-locks and dead locks.

As an interesting example, condition variables preserve scheduling order *only* if you take care to signal them under the mutex (if you don't, things will usually work unless your scheduling crucially depends on fair scheduling):

> [man `phtread_cond_signal`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)
>
> *The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()` functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling `pthread_cond_wait()` or `pthread_cond_timedwait()` have associated with the condition variable during their waits; **however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required**, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()`.*

Comment: sehe, the boost master to the rescue as usual!  In my case, I'm only using a `boost::unique_lock` and `boost::mutex` in multiple threads.  Do you happen to know if with that simple example the order of calls to `unique_lock` is preserved?  Thank you so much in advance sehe!

Comment: You need to look into the pthreads/Win32 documentation. I've tried to find compelling reasons why it cannot be anything else, but haven't thought of a pressing reason (_e.g. I don't think that arbitrarily changing the thread priorities will introduce potential for deadlock as long as the locks are acquired in consistent order_). Of course, if you want to design systems that respond predictably (prevent starvation/worst-case behaviour like soft-lock) under heavy load you would _want_ to refer to your platform's documentation for confirmation about it's scheduling priorities.

Comment: Thank you for the details sehe!  I'm all linux and still too inexperienced to get that deep, so I think I might try to fight through maintaining multiple lock order to prevent deadlocks instead of assuming that a lock might do this or that.  Thank you so much for sharing your amazing knowledge, again and again!!!